# How to dynamically get value of component p:inputText inside a datatable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces Datatable:

```
    <p:dataTable id="tabela" var="item"
        value="#{myBean.lista}"
        rowIndexVar="rowindex">

        <p:column>
            <p:inputText 
                required="true" id="inputAliquota" value="#{item.taxa}"
                >
            </p:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

In my backing bean I have a lista:

```
private List<Aliquota> lista;
```

And a Button to remove columns from my datatable:

```
            <p:commandLink
                immediate="true" id="botaoExcluir"
                action="#{myBean.excluirAliquota}"
                >
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}"
                    target="#{myBean.aliquota}" />
            </p:commandLink>
```

When I start the bean I populate "lista" with 5 empty Aliquota objects.

In excluirAliquota method I get the object that has to be removed, compare with the values of the List and delete it. But I'm having problems. When the user change the value of inputText the change don't reflect the Aliquota object on list.

My question is how to set this value without submit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reflect the value on the backing bean without submitting it. However, you can submit it using Ajax by adding a listener to the input text. The listener method doesn't have to do anything, it can be empty, but it needs to be there for an Ajax submit. It can be something like that:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabela" var="item"
    value="#{myBean.lista}"
    rowIndexVar="rowindex">

    <p:column>
        <p:inputText 
            required="true" id="inputAliquota" value="#{item.taxa}"
            >
            <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.dummyListener()}"/>
        </p:inputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

This will instantly reflect all changes in the inputText to the taxa field of the corresponding item. If that's what you want, you can use this method.

Comment: So, you never tried just `<p:ajax />`? The `listener` attribute is absolutely not a required attribute. Regardless, I believe OP actually faced a slight different problem. At least, that `immediate="true"` introduces quite a bit of ambiguity in the actual question.

Comment: I tried commandLink, but there was an error. The immediate = true is because I have validations on this form. In this way how I can associate the changed values to the list? I associate the method with event but I don't know how to get the values from the datatable.

Comment: I mean, is there a easy way to connect this values from the list of inputs to a dynamic list (that I can add and remove inputtexts from the datatable), without controlling it manually?

Comment: @BalusC I understand now your answer. I just have to put <p:ajax/> inside inputtext tag? I tried this, but the values are not binding to my ArrayList.

Comment: Then this confirms my suspicion that you've actually a different problem. It's sad to see that at least three users didn't see it.

Comment: adding: the scope of the Bean is RequestScope